# print list error NameError: name 'lst1' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I have a problem with this code when I tried to get the lst1 (print(lst1)) I get this error NameError: name 'lst1' is not defined

I tried like everything but can't get with the error

```
# bkm( [500, 1024, 2000, 1100000] ) <- input
# ['0MB 0KB 500B', '0MB 1KB 0B', '0MB 1KB 976B', '1MB 50KB 224B'] <-this should be the output


    def bkm(lst):
        lst1=[]
        for i in lst:
            mb=i/1048576
            i=i%1048576
            kb=i/1024
            b=i%1024
            lst1=lst1+[str(mb)+'MB'+' '+str(kb)+'KB'+' '+str(b)+'B']
        return lst1
    bkm( [500, 1024, 2000, 1100000] )
    print (lst1)
```

Comment: You're trying to access the variable outside the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the returned list

```
my_list = bkm([500, 1024, 2000, 1100000])
print(my_list)
```

`lst1` falls out of scope as soon as the `bkm` function is finished, so you need to use the returned list and store that in a new variable.